# How to increase plot frequency of gnuplot with c++ real-time data?

Tags: c++, gnuplot, real-time, iostream

I'm trying to visualize sensor data in real time using C++. The sensor has an output of up to 1kHz, but gnuplot is only plotting the data at about 10Hz.

I'm using gnuplot-iostream (http://stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/) to pipe the data to gnuplot from my C++ script, which is simple and easy. But it seems like the plotting process is slow, and takes 1/10th of a second to update the plot. Is there any way of increasing this frequency?

EDIT:
Here's an example of a simple code

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <gnuplot-iostream/gnuplot-iostream.h>

typedef std::pair<double, double> Point;

int main() {
  std::vector<Point> data;

  double x = 0.0;
  double y = 0.0;
  double c = 0.0;

  Gnuplot gp;
  gp << "set terminal wxt size 800, 400\n";

  while (x < 10000) {
    x += 0.01;
    y = sin(x);
    c += 0.01;
    data.push_back(Point(x,y));
    //std::cout <<  x << std::endl;
    if (c > 0.1) {
      gp << "plot '-' with lines title 'sin(x)'\n";
      gp.send1d(data);
      c = 0.0;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you going to be able to see 1kHz updates? Perhaps set a lower goal?

Comment: Are you regenerating the whole dataset file each time? Let's see a [MCVE]!

Comment: I don't need 1kHz updates, but maybe 100Hz is enough. The terminal is wxt (in Linux, i forgot to mention). The data is stored in boost:tuple with x and y values as doubles, in a vector. The vector is constantly appended with new data points, and then sent to gnuplot.

Comment: You watch TV at about 25 frames per second.

Comment: Still want to see a [MCVE] as that is a requirement here. Maybe the slowdown is in your code. And how you send the data to gnuplot is relevant.

Comment: I've added an example code now. Thank you for any help, I'm pretty new to C++.

Comment: Okay cool thanks better now

Answer (score 6):

If the sensor outputs data at 1 kHz sample rate, that absolutely doesn't mean that you should plot with that frequency. That's crazy! What's the point of plotting the data with that frequency if your eye can't see with that frequency?

You should group the points you want to plot like every 0.1 seconds, then plot them all together with all the data. To be clear:

1. Collect some data, put it in an array to be plotted
2. plot the data of the array
3. collect more data for 0.1 sec (or 0.2 or 0.5, or maybe every 100 samples; that's your call)
4. add it to the array of the data to be plotted
5. optional: trim the data from the front if the array is too large
6. plot the data
7. go back to 3

Comment: Aha I understand now. I've collected the data now into an array which is sent to gnuplot each time it is finished plotting. I get to see all my datapoints now, but the "framerate" is slower now, about 1-5 Hz, and it slows down as more points are added. After 30 sec I have 30 000 datapoints, is that just too much for gnuplot to handle efficiently, or?

Comment: @OveBaardsgaard which is why step 5 exists.